# Return from Ruby method but keep it running in background

Tags: ruby, multithreading, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I need to create a big List in MongoDB which contains more than 100,000 contacts (inserting List_Id into each contact record). So my idea for a solution is: add 100 contacts first, then return to the client so the UI can display the first 100 contacts. Then the rest of the contacts will be added later.

My problem is I want the process/method to keep running in the background while I return to client. My instinct says that thread would be a good solution for it.

Sample code:

```
def add_contacts_to_list
    count = 0
    thread = Thread.new{
      @contacts.each do |contact|
         add_to_list(contact, list_id)
         count = count + 1
         #what I want
            when count = 100, return to client, and the thread is still running like nothing happens
         #what I want
      end
    }
    thread.join
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach seems okay for a very small load application...

...however, if your application will run through heavy loads, you should address issues that are usually resolved using job queuing, such as:

- Multi-threading could corrupt data (even using MRI - the global lock's protection is limited).
- Creating too many threads could cause a significant slowdown that could make the app non-responsive.

Having said that, I will try and write examples for both approaches, using your approach for one separate thread per request and using a very simple home-made que.

Using your code and modifying it a bit to accommodate the fact that a thread will return immediately after it's creation, running in the background, your code might look something like this:

```
def add_contacts_to_list
    # create a proc, so the code doesn't repeat itself (DRY)
    the_job = Proc.new do |contact_list|
        contact_list.each {|c| add_to_list(c, @list_id)}
    end
    # get 100 contacts first
    the_job.call @contacts[0..99]
    # Send the rest to a thread
    thread = Thread.new { the_job.call @contacts[100..-1] }
    # that's it. we now return and the thread works in the background.
end
```

On the other hand, here is a simple Que module (just for demo), that could work better:

```
module SimpleQue
    QUE = []
    QUE_LOCKER = Mutex.new
    @kill_thread = false

    def self.que_job *args, &job
        raise "Cannot que jobs after que was set to finish!" if @kill_thread
        raise "Missing a job to que!" unless job
        QUE_LOCKER.synchronize { QUE << [job, args] }
        true 
    end

    THREAD = Thread.new do
        begin
            until @kill_thread && QUE.empty?
                sleep 0.5 while QUE_LOCKER.synchronize { QUE.empty? }
                job, args = QUE_LOCKER.synchronize { QUE.shift }
                job.call(*args)
            end
        rescue => e
            # change this to handle errors
            puts e
            retry
        end
    end

    def self.join
        @kill_thread = true
        THREAD.join
    end

end

# test it:
SimpleQue.que_job("hi!") {|s| sleep 1; puts s}
SimpleQue.que_job("nice!") {|s| sleep 1; puts s}
SimpleQue.que_job("hi!") {|s| sleep 1; puts s}
SimpleQue.que_job("hi!") {|s| sleep 1; puts s}
SimpleQue.que_job("yo!") {|s| sleep 1; puts s}
SimpleQue.que_job("bye!") {|s| sleep 1; puts s}
puts "sent everything to the que, now about to wait using #join."
SimpleQue.join
SimpleQue.que_job("hi?") {|s| sleep 1; puts s}

# adjusting your code, ignoring multithreading issues:

def add_contacts_to_list
    # create a proc, so the code doesn't repeat itself (DRY)
    the_job = Proc.new do |contact_list|
        contact_list.each {|c| add_to_list(c, @list_id)}
    end
    # get 100 contacts first
    the_job.call @contacts[0..99]
    # Send the rest to the que
    SimpleQue.que_job(@contacts[100..-1], &the_job)
    # that's it. we now return and the que works in the background.
end


# adjusting your code, adding basic multithreading safety:

def add_contacts_to_list
    # sending a job to the que:
    SimpleQue.que_job(@contacts) do |contact_list|
        contact_list.each {|c| add_to_list(c, @list_id)}
    end
    # I removed: the_job.call @contacts[0..99]
    # it's better if you didn't even start the first 100 contacts...
    # ...it might cause data corruption when different threads do it.
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation, I'm trying to apply it

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are on the right track in terms of using a separate thread to background the larger process. You may want to get the initial 100 results then submit a job to something like sidekiq or resque to run the larger operations. Threading is complex topic and different servers behave differently. The venerable Aaron Patterson (tenderlove) discusses it in this thread: http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/06/18/removing-config-threadsafe.html - That is actually the name of his domain and almost completely Safe For Work for what it's worth. If you are going to run such large processes you definitely need to move them out of the blocking request thread so again I would suggest looking into a job queue of some sort like the ones mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I will schedule it to background (sidekiq or something) and redirect client to page where contacts can be displayed. Taking thread management is unnecesarry risk in my opinion for such feature.

```
@contacts.take(100).each { |contact| add_to_list(contact) }
perform_async
return_to_client
```